# Improper output of the following String programs

Tags: java, string

```
public class NoOfConsAlphabet {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str="aaabbddaabbcc";
    int count=1;
    String finalString="";
    for(int i=1;i<str.length()-1;i++)
        {
            if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(i+1))
            {
                ++count;

            }
            else
            {

                finalString+=str.charAt(i)+count+",";
                count=1;
            }   

        }
    System.out.println(finalString);
    }
}
```

I am getting this as my o/p:99,100,102,99,100, Can someone tell me how to get this resolved not sure what this is?Need to get an output of a3,b2,d2,a2,b2,

Comment: `char` + `int` => `int`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `+` operator on a a `char` and an `int` leads to a `char` representing the sum of the both (and does not concatenate). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317631/java-char-int-conversions) answer for a detailed explanation and exceptions.

So, the statement

```
finalString+=str.charAt(i)+count+",";
```

Ends up being char + int addition and not string concatenation.

To concatenate, convert the `str.charAt(i)+` to `String` first.

Answer (score 3):

You essentially add:

```
char + int + String
```

Since `+` is left associative, you end up doing:

```
(char + int) + String
```

therefore `int + String`; and only at that step is the string concatenation happening.

A solution would be to use `String.format()`:

```
String.format("%c%d,", str.charAt(i), count);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
str.charAt(i)+count+","
```

That's performing a `char` + `int` conversion, which is just integer arithmetic, because `+` is left-associative. The resulting integer is *then* converted to a string when `","` is concatenated with it.

So this:

```
finalString+=str.charAt(i)+count+",";
```

is equivalent to:

```
int tmp1 = str.charAt(i)+count;
String tmp2 = tmp1 + ",";
finalString += tmp2;
```

I suggest you use:

```
String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)) + count
```

to force string concatenation. Better yet, use a `StringBuilder`:

```
builder.append(str.charAt(i)).append(count).append(",");
```

That's clearer *and* more efficient :)