# Android: Connvert Int to char

Tags: java, char, int

I first converted a `char` to an `int` and then the `int` to a binary string. Then I tried to convert this `int` back to a `char` but I got an error.

I tried this:

```
char myasciireturn =  (char) intname;
```

And I got the following error:

> Inconvertable types; cant cast 'java.lang.Integer' to 'char'

Here is my code:

```
Integer tester = Integer.valueOf("01000001", 2);
nextstep = Character.toString((char) tester);
```

Thanks for your help in advance,
Max

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - char, int conversions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317631/java-char-int-conversions)

Comment: converting int to char and converting Integer to char are different. You can use `int tester = Integer.valueOf("01000001", 2);`, that shouldn't give you problem when converting the `int tester` to char later on

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is the size of the Integer. Where `tester` is greater than eight bits, there are no characters to cast that number to. I would do this instead:
First, convert the binary number back to a decimal number. (For help with that go to this link: http://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/java-program-for-binary-to-decimal-conversion/)
After the number is decimal, this is how to convert an int to a char:

```
int tester = 132; //Or whatever the decimal number is
char letter = (char)tester;
```

I hope that this is useful.