# Is it typecasting or something else in java?

Tags: java

```
for(int i=0; i < 26; i++) {

alphabet[i] = (char)('a' + i);
```

hello, please explain  what does the second line mean. Is it type casting from char to int?

Comment: `'a' + i` is an `int`; `(char) 'a' + i` casts the `int` back to a `char`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - char, int conversions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317631/java-char-int-conversions)

Comment: *"Is it type casting from char to int?"* No, it's typecasting from `int` (the result of `'a' + i`) to `char`.

Answer (score 1):

When you perform arithmetic operations in data types shorter than `int` for example, shorts, bytes and chars, the end result of the operation is returned as an `int`.

Thus in your case `'a' +i` is an operation on char and int. So the result is an `int`.

So if you want a character back from this operation it is mandatory for you to perform an explicit cast.

So the operation here is a type cast from `int` to `char`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a cast from `int` to `char`. Addition of `int` and `char` (`'a' + i`) make the expression of wider type.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I came to know it is typecasting syntax it has to be written in that manner.