# Output in java (System.out.println())

Tags: java, string, char, int, output

In Java :

```
System.out.println('c' + "Hello world" + 1);
```

gives

```
cHello world1
```

but

```
System.out.println('c' + 1 + "Hello world");
```

gives

```
100Hello world
```

i.e c is converted to its ASCII character.What rule does Java use for this?Can someone tell me the set of rules which I can follow to predict the output as this has become quite confusing for me.

Comment: If you add something to a string, it concatenates. That's the only time `+` concatenates. If you add a char to an int, it adds them numerically.

Comment: Impossible. You can get `100`, not `120`.

Comment: take a look to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317631/java-char-int-conversions)

Comment: Well, not ASCII, UTF-16 (which is one of several character encodings for the Unicode character set). Java doesn't use ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

The `+` operator becomes String concatenation operator only if the left-hand side is the `String`. Otherwise it remains the additive operator as per [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).

In your example `'c'` is a char literal, which gets promoted to `int` during addition. Do note that `c` is 99, not 119 as in your example so the output is `100Hello world`.

Answer (score 2):

because `char` in Java play two roles one as a String when you concatenate it with a String and the second as an int when you sum it with another numeric value.

So in your case :

```
System.out.println('c' + 1 + "Hello world");
```

Is equivalent to :

```
System.out.println(('c' + 1) + "Hello world");
                   ^       ^
```

where 'c' transform it to `99` :

```
System.out.println((99 + 1) + "Hello world");
                   ^^^    ^
```

For that you get :

```
100Hello world
```